# New AndroidStudio 2.3 Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have just installed new Android Studio and tried to create a new project. But I get this strange error. I am using 32 bit Linux system.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
>
> Information:Total time: 14.838 secs
>
> Information:2 errors
>
> Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sandesh.testing"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
 }
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: gradle file please

Comment: @JaydeepPatel, added please check

Comment: main project gradle file or version?

Comment: upgrade it to 2.3.0 it will work.
like : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

Comment: @JaydeepPatel, it is already `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'`

Comment: I am using 32 bit system. will that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your case problem is  newest Android Studio does not run on 32bit only system. On download page you can check the requirement also:

> 64-bit distribution capable of running 32-bit applications

The newest version does not support 32bit. I think you should try with one solution but I dont know how long it will work :

```
Step1.Go to terminal
Step2.type gedit .profile
Step3.paste the below line at end of the page
Step4.export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
Step5.type source .profile in terminal or restart system
```

Please remember that may be in future Android Stdio stop supporting this too so its better you should move to **bit64**  or downgrade your version of android studio.